# How can I import numeric.js to my javascript file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, numeric

I'm trying to use [`numeric.js`](https://github.com/sloisel/numeric/blob/master/src/numeric.js) to my javascript file in my `Vue` project.

```
import * as numeric from '@/libs/numeric.js';
...
numeric.spline(dds, xys);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: _libs_numeric_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.spline is not a function

How can I fix it?

Comment: This should work  `import numeric from @/libs/numeric';`

Comment: [`numeric`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeric) is on NPM so you don't need to reference it via `libs/numeric.js`. Install it normally, ie `npm install numeric` and then import it as indicated by @dreijntjens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric.js should be installed through the npm like so:

```
npm install numeric
```

you can then easily import it:

```
import numeric from @/libs/numeric';
```

Comment: install npm and import numeric from 'numeric'; works.