# How to import "numeric": "^1.2.6" in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I have installed package ["numeric": "^1.2.6"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numeric)

And types:  `"@types/numeric": "^1.2.1"`

I try to import this in Angular app:

```
import * as numeric from 'numeric';
```

Then I get this error on the line:

```
  let x = numeric.solve(m, xs);
```

Erorr is:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: numeric is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I import numeric.js to my javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110946/how-can-i-import-numeric-js-to-my-javascript-file)

Comment: No, after installing and import I get this:
import numeric from '@/libs/numeric';
Cannot find module '@/libs/numeric' or its corresponding type declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The provided version of the numeric package does not include an `index.js` file, which means you have to include the script in your `angular.json`

*angular.json*

```json
{
  "architect": {
    "projects": {
      "your-app-name": {
        "build": {
          "scripts": [] <-- change this
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When you've made your change it should look something like this, if you have no other imported scripts.

```json
{
  "architect": {
    "projects": {
      "your-app-name": {
        "build": {
          "scripts": ["node_modules/numeric/numeric-1.2.6.js"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Stop and restart your `ng serve` after updating your `angular.json` for the change to take effect.

### What does this do

Adding the script to your `angular.json` scripts will make numeric available on your `window` object in the browser: `window.numeric`

However, since you also downloaded the typings, you can import these typings in your components using `import * as numeric from 'numeric'` and utilize the numeric namespace which the typings have exported.

```
import * as numeric from 'numeric';
@Component({...}) export class SomeComponent {
 x = numeric.solve(x,v);
}
```

Since the import is merely type information it should be stripped away when your TypeScript is transpiled to JS, and the numeric call should work because it is globally available on the window.

Comment: this does not work for me